# What does E(X + Y) mean?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

I am working on some problems in probability theory and keep getting stuck on some of the concepts regrading expected values. I understand that if you have one dice roll you would have a distribution of $X$ with values taking ie. $P(X=1) = {1 \over 6}$, but how do you interpret this when you are considering two die rolls? Understanding that these are independent you would essentially get the same distribution.

Question: What is the distribution of $(X + Y)$ and how would you calculate $E(X + Y)$ if $X$ represents the first roll and $Y$ represents the second roll?

Is this just the same as $E(X) + E(Y)$?

Part 2: If you are trying to find $E(2X - 2)$ do you subtract two from each different value? For example $[2 * 1 * {1 \over 6} - 2] + [2 * 2 * {1 \over 6} -2]$...

Comment: Expectation is linear, so $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$ and $E[\alpha X]= \alpha E[X]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No matter whether X and Y are dependent or independent, $$E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)$$

Coming to $E(2X-2)$, it can be easily written as $E(2X) - E(2)$ which in turn equals to $2E(X)-2$.

Comment: That answers my question perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: glad to help you

Comment: One further point of clarification, do the distributions follow this same rule? So distribution of (X + Y) is 1/6 + 1/6 for each outcome?

Comment: No. You cannot add the distributions. Considering $Z=X+Y$, $P(Z=z)$ can be written as $\sum_{x+y=z} P_{X,Y}(x,y) =\sum_{x+y=z} P_{X,Y}(x,z-x) = \sum_{x+y=z} P_{X}(x)P_{Y}(z-x) $.

Comment: For example, $P(X+Y=3)=P(Z=3)=P_{X}(1)P_{Y}(2)+P_{X}(2)P_{Y}(1) = 2/36$

Comment: As I explained above, $Z$ is a Random Variable taking values from {$2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12$} with probabilities {$\dfrac{1}{36},\dfrac{2}{36},\dfrac{3}{36},\dfrac{4}{36},\dfrac{5}{36},\dfrac{6}{36},\dfrac{5}{36},\dfrac{4}{36},\dfrac{3}{36},\dfrac{2}{36},\dfrac{1}{36}$}

Comment: I didn't completely understand your question. But if you want $X+Y=6$, the number of $(x,y)$ combinations will be {$(1,5),(2,4),(3,3),(4,2),(5,1)$}. If you want the value of $P(X+Y=6)$, then add the probabilities of each of $(x,y)$ combination. So, you get,  $P(X+Y=6) = \dfrac{5}{36}$

Comment: $E(2X+3Y)=2E(X)+3E(Y)$. and $E(X)=E(Y)=\dfrac{21}{6}$

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables with same distribution. So the statistical averages will be same for both.

Comment: how did you get 21/6 though?

Comment: $E(X) = \sum_{x=1}^{6}xp(x) = \dfrac{1+2+3+4+5+6}{6} = \dfrac{21}{6}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83634/discussion-between-ethan-and-narendra-deconda).

Answer (score 0):

The expected value operator is "linear"

$E[X+Y] = E[X] + E[Y]\\
E[aX] = aE[X]\\
E[2X + Y + 2] = 2E[X] + E[Y] + 2$